# How can one copy a directory tree from one drive to another, replicating any junction points, under Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I have an NTFS drive that I want to copy a whole directory tree, which has a few junctions throughout it, but preserve the junctions so that they point to the same relative places on the new drive (also NTFS) in order to achieve a true cloning.

That is, if the old drive had a junction `O:\abc\def\ghi\Bar` that points to `O:\abc\Foo`, then I'd want to end up with `N:\Blah\abc\def\ghi\Bar` pointing to `N:\Blah\abc\Foo`

**RoboCopy** doesn''t seem have an option for this (and Google seems to confirm this.)

I've also tried **FastCopy** which at first seem to do the trick until I realized that `N:\Blah\abc\def\ghi\Bar` was pointing to `O:\abc\Foo` instead of `N:\Blah\abc\Foo`

Thanks.

Comment: What about `mklink`

Comment: I don't have that on this system. I don't think it does copying though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had great success using [Link Shell Extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/linkshellextension.html), using it's `Smart Copy` and `Smart Mirror` options (which you can invoke when dragging the directories to be copied using the *right* mouse button and choosing from the `Drop Here` sub-menu.)

This will copy the whole directory tree, all sub-directories and files within, and replicate junctions, symlinks, hardlinks, et al, adjusting them so they point to the same relative location within the newly copied tree.